# How to get or access navigation params in functional component in react native

Tags: react-native, parameters, react-functional-component

I am new to react native. I have created 3 screen. one is login from where I navigate to 2 screens. first screen is class based component and second screen is functional based component. Now I can get params in class component screen like this = >

```
const leadTagNumber = this.props.route.params.leadTagNumber
```

here is working fine
but Now I want to get that params in functional component too. so how to do that in functional component. please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this syntax:

```js
function MyComp(props){

//
   const yourParam = props.route.params.yourParam
//
}
```

Comment: be sure to add `props` as argument to your functional component definition

Comment: how to add that

Comment: just like in the answer `function MyComp(props)`, post your component code if possible

Comment: ok fine but now error is = undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.route')

Comment: your component should be added in the navigation stack to access `props.route` or `props.navigation`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in the functional component is to use `useRoute()` functional hook.

1. Call the function and import

   `const route = useRoute();`
2. Import hook in the top

   `import {useNavigation, useRoute} from '@react-navigation/native';`
3. Get your value which you had passed from another screen anywhere in your code

   `route?.params?.mobileNumber`